# Shell variable assignment automatically escapes '['

Tags: bash, shell, regex

I am trying to determine if a string contains regular expression in shell (`bash`).
Specifically, if it contains a digit.
And while this:

```
$ [[ string_with[6]indice =~ [0-9] ]] && echo "True" || echo "False"
```

works as expected, when I assign LHS and RHS to variables, something odd happens:

```
$ STR=string_with[6]indice
$ REGEX=[0-9]
$ [[ string_with[6]indice =~ [0-9] ]] && echo "True" || echo "False"
False
```

I wanted to see what does shell expend my variables to, and found out this:

```
$ STR=string_with[6]indice
+ STR='string_with[6]indice'
$ REGEX=[0-9]
+ REGEX='[0-9]'
$ [[ $STR =~ "$REGEX" ]] && echo "True" || echo "False"
+ [[ string_with[6]indice =~ \[0-9] ]]
+ echo False
False
```

Where did this `\` in front of `[0-9]` come from, and why does the shell automatically escape the first bracket `[` in  `REGEX`?

Comment: It's all a bit irrational: I've done some tests and it doesn't seem to matter whether you double-quote `$STR` or not (unless there is an embedded blank), but quoting `$REGEX` gives what you observe, while omitting the quotes works. Double-quoting the literal search pattern behaves similarly. I image there will be problems if there is a single-digit file name in the current directory. I would single-quote both variable assignments to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have double-quotes around `$REGEX`. When matching with the `=~` operator, quoted sections of the pattern are treated literally. That is, regex metacharacters in the quoted sections are treated as if they were escaped. Compare the effect when the pattern is in quotes:

```
$ # Pattern in variable, quoted:
$ [[ $STR =~ "$REGEX" ]] && echo "True" || echo "False"
+ [[ string_with[6]indice =~ \[0-9] ]]
+ echo False
False
$ # Pattern directly in command, quoted:
$ [[ $STR =~ "[0-9]" ]] && echo "True" || echo "False"
+ [[ string_with[6]indice =~ \[0-9] ]]
+ echo False
False
```

with the effect without quotes:

```
$ # Pattern in variable, NOT quoted:
$ [[ $STR =~ $REGEX ]] && echo "True" || echo "False"
+ [[ string_with[6]indice =~ [0-9] ]]
+ echo True
True
$ # Pattern directly in command, NOT quoted:
$ [[ $STR =~ [0-9] ]] && echo "True" || echo "False"
+ [[ string_with[6]indice =~ [0-9] ]]
+ echo True
True
```

This is one of the very few cases where you *don't* want to quote a variable reference.

BTW, I recommend using lowercase or mixed-case variable names in shell scripting; that way you don't run the risk of conflicting with some environment variable that has special meaning to the shell or other programs (`$PATH` is the classic example).